# Apache Parquet data storage engine?

Tags: java, apache-spark, parquet

From link [sql-data-sources-parquet](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html) I see below code snippet stores the data parquet format but
per mine understanding from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Parquet) is just a format not a storage engine. So Parquet will stores
the data in specific format on some storage engine like HDFS/S3/Cassandra etc. Is n't it ? So my question is where below code snippet will 
store th data as I do not see any mention of storage engine like HDFS/S3/Cassandra etc

```
Dataset<Row> peopleDF = spark.read().json("examples/src/main/resources/people.json");

// DataFrames can be saved as Parquet files, maintaining the schema information
peopleDF.write().parquet("people.parquet");

// Read in the Parquet file created above.
// Parquet files are self-describing so the schema is preserved
// The result of loading a parquet file is also a DataFrame
Dataset<Row> parquetFileDF = spark.read().parquet("people.parquet");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is deduced from the URL scheme, for example `s3://examples/src/main/resources/people.json` or `hdfs://examples/src/main/resources/people.json`. The mapping from scheme to `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` implementations is maintained in hadoop configuration. For example

```
<property><name>fs.s3.impl</name><value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value></property>
```

would map `s3://...` to `S3AFileSystem` and there are defaults for some common file systems in case they are not explicitly configured.

Comment: But as I said in code snippet I mentioned I do not see any mention of S3/HDFS . So will file be stored here ?

Comment: No, I think it default to local file system when the scheme is not specified. Use `s3://some/path/people.parquet` to store to S3 or `hdfs://some/path/people.parquet` to store to HDFS.